# Array from i values in loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I've made a loop to tell me the array element which is less than a certain number (i.e. 1e4) but is there a way I put all these values easily into an array? The data file is quite large so doing it by hand is possible but not a great use of time. Please and thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you give an example of your code that isn't working and any error messages?  Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
newarray = [num for num in oldarray if num < YOUR_CERTAIN_NUMBER]
```

Demo:

```
oldarray = [1, 2, 40, 50]
newarray = [num for num in oldarray if num < 30]
print newarray
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark the answer correct by ticking the "V" on the left. Thanks.